# How to return one row but concatenate the reason column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, grouping, sql-server-group-concat

I have an sql server 2012 database table which contains data just like below:

```
id    import_id    tenancyname    owner    reason
----- ----------   ------------   -----    ------
1      1            test          null     Owner is missing
2      2            null          null     Tenancy Name is Missing
2      2            null          null     Owner is Missing
```

As you can see from the data above there are 2 reasons for row id 2, because there are 2 things wrong with that row.

Now what im trying to do is to only return the row once but concatenate the reasons into 1 cell so it will look like the following:

```
id    import_id    tenancyname    owner    reason
----- ----------   ------------   -----    ------
1      1            test          null     Owner is missing
2      2            null          null     Tenancy Name is Missing \newline Owner is Missing
```

help please from the experts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does SQL server support GROUP_CONCAT? If it does, do select id, import_id, tenancyname, owner, group_concat(reason) from tablename group by id, import_id, tenancyname, owner

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.import_id, A.tenancyname, A.owner, MAX(STUFF(fxMerge.reason, 1, 1, '')) 
FROM tableA A
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT ',' + reason 
    FROM tableA A1
    WHERE A.import_id = A1.import_id 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) fxMerge (reason) 
GROUP BY A.id, A.import_id, A.tenancyname, A.owner
```

Comment: Yours works perfectly but how do i put a newline rather than a comma in the reason? This is so when it goes into excel the reasons are in a list

Answer (score 1):

This question has answers, but there is a "right" way to approach it.  Some of the answers are incomplete.

You want:

```
select id, import_id, tenancyname, owner,
       stuff((select '
' + reason
             from table t2
             where t2.id = t.id
             for xml path ('concat'), type
            ).value('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
            1, 1, '')
from table t
group by id, import_id, tenancyname, owner;
```

It is important to use `value` to pull the value out, because this fixes the problem of characters getting converted to xml equivalents (`&amp;` instead of `&`, for instance).